# Use template to overcome the lack of a base class?

Tags: c++, templates, std

Obviously, standard containers don't have a common base class, nor a common interface, although the method names are homogeneous.

The problem : I have to fill a container with a collection of objects of a unique type. The container can be a `std::list`, a `std::vector` or a `std::deque`, and possibly some other custom container. Is the following code the best solution ?

```
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
# include <list>
# include <vector>
# include <deque>

/*
 * Fill a container with two strings. The container
 * must expose the `clear` and `push_back` methods.
 */
template<typename T>
void f(T & t)
{
    t.clear() ;

    t.push_back("Alice") ;
    t.push_back("Bob") ;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::list<std::string>    l ;
    std::vector<std::string>  v ;
    std::deque<std::string>   q ;

    f(l) ;   // fill the list
    f(v) ;   // fill the vector
    f(q) ;   // fill the double-ended queue

    // possibly anything with `clear` and `push_back` methods
    // can be filled with `f`

    return 0 ;
}
```

Thanks for any advice !

---

**EDIT**

Here is the case that I illustrated with `f` in my first post :

```
struct AudioFormat
{
    uint32_t   samplerate ;   // Sampling frequency
    uint8_t    channels ;     // The number of channels
    uint8_t    bitdepth ;     // The number of bits per sample
} ;

class AudioDevice
{
    // many stuff skipped
    public :
      /*
       * Fills the container with available audio formats handled properly by the device
       */
      void GetSupportedAudioFormats(std::list<AudioFormat> &) ;
    // many stuff skipped
} ;
```

I am looking for a better way to declare `GetSupportedFormats` so it can handle many other containers, not only `std::list`s. That's the point of my first post.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question.  The choice of list, vector or deque depends on what you need to do with the objects.  None is "better" than the others.

Comment: @Carey Gregory: That's why I want `f` to be somewhat "generic" : It can handle `list`, `vector`, `deque`, ... depending on the situation and on my choice.

Comment: @overcoder -- generic algorithms work with iterators, not values. And there is a limit how general you can be, there is a reason why there are different categories of iterators, you can't make one size fits all.

Comment: @Gene: Generic algorithms would be better off working with ranges (which containers are).

Comment: @Gene: even granted that the algorithms in `<algorithm>` work with iterators, they are not the only algorithms in the world, nor are they the only generic code. There's nothing especially wrong with writing generic code that acts on containers directly, considering that there are some common operations (like the erase-remove idiom, or in this case emptying) that absolutely require using the container. Operations that can be implemented using only iterators should be (if you follow the standard library idiom, that is), this is one that can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite would be:

```
/*
 * Fill a container with two strings. The container
 * must expose the `clear` and `push_back` methods.
 */
template<typename T>
void f(T & t)
{
    t.clear() ;

    std::insert_iterator<T> it(t, t.end());
    *it++ = "Alice";
    *it++ = "Bob";
}
```

The constraints are now: `clear` and `insert`, so it will also work with `std::set` for example. Also, it could work with any type, you would just have to specialise the `std::insert_iterator` template for it.

Comment: @GMan: Could you propose an implementation for `f` using directly iterators ?

Comment: @overcoder: Just keep the code in this answer, but make the top `template <typename OutIter> void f(OutIter it)`, and call it like this, for example: `f(std::back_inserter(v))`.

Comment: @GMan: remember that we need to `clear()` first, so `f` would have to take the container *and* the iterator.

Comment: @Steve: I disagree. (You're right, I mean, but the design ought to change).  What if I want to append to existing data? Why would I clear in the function? If I want my container clear I'll just do it before I call the function.

Comment: @GMan: well, you can play a funny video of a cat if you prefer, but *in this question*, the request is for a generic function that clears a container and then puts two strings in it. If you don't want to write that function, jog on ;-) Granted, it might be worth writing a function `g` that just does the inserts, since that's a clearly identifiable sub-task, but there's still `f` to be written.

Comment: @PierreBdR: Just a little comment : the `++` are unnecessary for the insert iterator.

Comment: @Steve: And *in this question*, the design could be better. Clearing shouldn't be up to the function, if the functions primary purpose is to fill something with data. (In the OP's example, the clear is redundant, for example.)

Comment: @Steve (with edit): Right, so let's say we've written `g`, which does the inserts. What gain is there in `f`? I very much doubt `c.clear();` is such an enormous burden that we need to make a new function for it. :/

Comment: @GMan: depends how common this "reset to two strings" operation is in the code base, I would say. It's difficult to see how "make a container contain precisely the strings `"Alice"` and `"Bob"` is a heavily-used operation, but with a more concrete example of an operation that logically makes sense, and especially if it's used a few times in different places, I don't see why we should refuse on principle ever to pass a container to a function.

Comment: So, if it turns out that in fact the container always needs to be cleared before being populated, then I think your design is worse. It divides something that could be one logical operation into two, and imposes a requirement on the user to remember to do both. That said, there are other ways to reset a container in this way -- returning by value a new container with the right values might work perfectly well, or providing a suitable iterator pair so that the user can do `l.assign(first_str(), last_str());`, etc.

Comment: @Steve: We completely agree, I just really doubt this is something that needs much thought. The concern in this question isn't about how to `clear()` a container, that's trivial; it's about how to generically insert, so that's what the function we write should do, hence my comments that the clear is unnecessary and ought to be removed. If his use case *does* clear a lot, then sure: make the utility function to do so. But for the question, focus on the single task at hand.

Comment: @GMan: OK, seems we agree on design but disagree on the meaning of the question ;-) Given that the example code clears, I took "fill a container with a collection of objects" to mean replace the contents. Fair enough if you didn't.

Answer (score 3):

That's one solution.

A more "STL" style solution is to use a [`std::back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/)

```
char const* names[2] = { "Alice", "Bob" };

std::list<std::string> l;
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::deque<std::string> q;  

std::copy(names, names+2, std::back_inserter(l));
std::copy(names, names+2, std::back_inserter(v));
std::copy(names, names+2, std::back_inserter(q));
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide your own abstract class with methods clear() and add()

```
class ContainerIterface
{
public:
  virtual void clear() = 0;
  virtual void add(const UniqueType &e) = 0;
};
```

and then you can derive from it something like

```
template <typename Container>
class TemplatedContainer : public ContainerIntarface {
  virtual void clear() {c_.clear();}
  virtual void add(const UniqueType &e) {std::inserter(c_, c_.end()) = e;}

private:
  Container c_;
};
```

This assumes that you only have one type to store in the container. If that's not so, your base class becomes a temaplate too, and the derived class requires a template argument that is a template (`std::vector` rather than `std::vector<UniqueType>`)

Comment: @Arkadly: Thanks ! I'll investigate your proposition.

Comment: I don't see what `ContainerIterface` is bringing to the party. Generic code works fine without common base-classes, in fact that's kind of the point.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: It brings runtime polymorphism. OP doesn't need that in his original example, but it could be needed at some time in the future.

Comment: Maybe the ContainerInterface makes it possible to not use templates in all your code. Normal functions will also work: void f(ContainerInterface &c);

Comment: @Peter Alexander: excellent, if it's needed in future then I can add it *in future* ;-p

Comment: Indeed, it's intended as a bridge between generic and OO code, between compile-type polymorphism and run-time one. Of course, if you need this, chances are you need to reconsider your design, but that's not always an option.